# Google Maps API script tag

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a very simple PHP & HTML page, which I want to use the Google Maps API. If I uncomment the first two Javascript lines, it works and I get an alert pop. If I uncomment the second two Javascript lines, with the googlemap API, I get an error in the page, and PHP code gets totally en error in it, nothing loads. Can you help me fix this problem? How can we load googlemap API ?

```
<?php 
echo '<html>';
echo '<head>';

#echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
#echo "alert('Your message has been send successfully');";

#echo "<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">";
#echo "</script>";

echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo 'This is source';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>'; 
?>
```

Comment: you should be more consistent in your usage of quotation marks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest `<script>` tags.
To fix your problem, separate the two scripts:

```
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Your message has been send successfully');</script>";

echo "<script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'>";
echo "</script>";
```

Also make sure that your parentheses within parentheses are replaced with apostrophes or vice versa.
It would also help to see the error message, but this nesting error is the most flagrant one.

Comment: You're correct, but it would be better to show the OP the complete solution, and not just point the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to close script tag before requesting googleapis script

```
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
echo "alert('Your message has been send successfully');";
echo "</script>";
echo "<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>";
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo 'This is source';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
```